# Getting SqlBulkCopy to show up as sql in MiniProfiler

Tags: c#, sqlbulkcopy, mvc-mini-profiler

I'm using MiniProfiler to profile my sql commands.

One issue I'm dealing with now is repeated INSERT statements generated by linq.

I've converted them into a `SqlBulkCopy` command, however now it doesn't appear to record it in the sql view in MiniProfiler.

Would there even be an associated command string for a SqlBulkCopy?

Is it possible to get the bulk copy to appear in the list of sql commands?

Can I at least make it counted in the % sql bit?

---

I'm aware I could use `MiniProfiler.Current.Step("Doing Bulk Copy")` but that wouldn't count as SQL, and wouldn't show in the listing with any detail.

---

Current code below:

```
public static void BulkInsertAll<T>(this DataContext dc, IEnumerable<T> entities)
{
    var conn = (dc.Connection as ProfiledDbConnection).InnerConnection as SqlConnection;
    conn.Open();

    Type t = typeof(T);

    var tableAttribute = (TableAttribute)t.GetCustomAttributes(
        typeof(TableAttribute), false).Single();
    var bulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(conn)
    {
        DestinationTableName = tableAttribute.Name
    };

    //....

    bulkCopy.WriteToServer(table);
}
```

Comment: The data is being sent as special TDS packets, but I don't know whether the `BULK INSERT` is being initiated using SQL. It shows up in SQL Profiler as SQL, but that may be fake.

Comment: I'm working on [MiniProfiler 3.0](https://github.com/MiniProfiler/dotnet) that adds a more generic `CustomTiming` class, allowing you to profile the "bulk copy" and have it show up in the UI the same way "sql" does.  Once it's out, I'll answer with an example.

Comment: @JarrodDixon: Great! Any idea on timescale (beyond 6-8 weeks)? :)

Comment: This weekend, I hope... going to start testing it internally today.

Comment: @JarrodDixon: Cool, looks like I timed my question pretty well!

Comment: @JarrodDixon: Sorry to pester, but is there any news on this? I see it's getting updated on Git, but doesn't appear as an update on NuGet.

Comment: We're still dog-fooding it internally before releasing it on nuget; feel free to [build it from git](https://github.com/MiniProfiler/dotnet) in the interim.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should be able to use `CustomTimings` to profile these. These are included in the [new v3 version](https://github.com/MiniProfiler/dotnet/releases/tag/v3.0.10-beta) that is now [available on nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MiniProfiler/3.0.10-beta4).

You can see some example usages of `CustomTiming` in [the sample project](https://github.com/MiniProfiler/dotnet/blob/master/Sample.Mvc/Controllers/HomeController.cs#L100) where this is used to record http and redis events.

An example of how you could use it with `SqlBulkCopy`:

```
string sql = GetBulkCopySql(); // what should show up for the SqlBulkCopy event?
using (MiniProfiler.Current.CustomTiming("SqlBulkCopy", sql)) 
{
  RunSqlBulkCopy(); // run the actual SqlBulkCopy operation
}
```